# Look a message's text from events api response

Tags: slack-api

I'm using slacks [events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) and have setup a subscription to the [reactions_added](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added) event. Now when a reaction is added to a message, slack will send me a post body with all the details of the dispatched event as [described here](https://api.slack.com/events-api#event_type_structure).

The problem I'm having is that I want to get the details, specifically the `text` of the message that my users have reacted to so I can parse/store etc that specific message. I assumed the message would return with some type of UUID that I could then respond to the callback and get the text, however I'm find it difficult to get the specific message.

The only endpoint I see available is the `channels.history`, which doesn't seem to give me the granularity I'm looking for.

So the tl;dr is: How do I look up a via slacks API, a messages text sent from the events API? Give the information I have the event_ts, channel and message ts I thought would be enough. I'm using the ruby slack-api gem FWIW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use the method **`channels.history`**  (https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) to retrieve message from a public channel . The `reaction_added` dispatched event includes the channel ID and timestamp of the original message (in the `item`) and the combination of channelId + timestamp  should be unique.

Be careful that you use the correct timestamp though.  You need to use `item.ts` not `event_ts`

Full example dispatched event from the docs:

```
{
    "token": "z26uFbvR1xHJEdHE1OQiO6t8",
    "team_id": "T061EG9RZ",
    "api_app_id": "A0FFV41KK",
    "event": {
            "type": "reaction_added",
            "user": "U061F1EUR",
            "item": {
                    "type": "message",
                    "channel": "C061EG9SL",
                    "ts": "1464196127.000002"
            },
            "reaction": "slightly_smiling_face"
    },
    "event_ts": "1465244570.336841",
    "type": "event_callback",
    "authed_users": [
            "U061F7AUR"
    ]}
```

So calling `channels.history` with these values set should work:

- latest = item.ts value
- oldest = item.ts value
- inclusive = 1
- channel = item.channel value

If you want to get messages from a private channel you need to use `groups.history`.

https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history

Comment: `mpim.history` is for mult party direct message channels only. It will not work for normal channels.

Comment: channels.history event deprecated. But You can use the codes below new event conversations.history

`await slackClient.conversations.history({
    channel: event.item.channel,
    latest: event.item.ts,
    oldest: event.item.ts,
    inclusive: 1

  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.messages[0].text);
  });`